# Pronunciation of: <kinder> than

Tags: pronunciation

> He is kind.

> She is kinder than him.

Some dictionaries do not give a phonetic representation for *kinder*, and the ones that do, use a short vowel sound as in *kindergarten* and not a long vowel as in *kind* itself.

I do not recall I have ever heard it spoken in my life. So I would like to confirm the pronunciation and make sure it is not meant for another meaning.

**Edit:**

It turned out that the Oxford Dictionaries entry was for a [noun](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/pronunciation/english/kinder). The other dictionary I checked, Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, does not give any details about the word, just phonetic symbols and audio. I must admit I missed the difference between the noun and the adjective.

Comment: The only time you would pronounce it like *kindergarten* is if it's an abbreviation of *kindergarten*... "My daughter starts kinder this year." Otherwise, it's pronounced as you would expect..

Comment: Could you add a link or reference to dictionaries where the "kinder" short vowel sound is given? Maybe there is a mystery usage. But I think *kinder* pronounced as in *kindergarten* will point to a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: @user3169 You're right, it was a [noun](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/pronunciation/english/kinder). I usually start with Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, which in this particular case, unfortunately, did not give any details about the word, zilch.

Comment: -1 because the question suffers from an absence of any source exemplifying the user's statement.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure which dictionaries you are using but "kinder" could only be pronounced with a short /ɪ/ when used a an abbreviation of kindergarten, or a borrowing from German (e.g. the Kinder Transport). The vowel sound in "kinder" is the "long i", to rhyme with finder.

Neither "kind" nor "kinder" have true long vowel. Instead they have a dipthong made of an "a" and and "i" sound [/kaɪndə/](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kinder).